# UIFont not working on all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, uifont

I have a question:
I added a custom font into one of my apps, i imported the files. The files are also in build resources, I added the fonts to the info.plist file and I changed the font of the label just like this:

```
self.infoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-CondensedLight" size:11];
```

This works, on a lot of devices, but when i build the app, this font is not shown, instead i get the system font.

What could be wrong?

Comment: to use that font, u have to jailbreak ur iphone/ipad and install cydia and u have to use bytafont to get that font

Comment: Quit Xcode and delete derived data (also from trash) and open the project again hold CMD+SHIFT+K, and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Pl. check if you Target>Build Phases> Copy Bundle Resources has this font. If it is not present, then we have these issues.

Also, pl. go through this commmon [mistakes](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/). Will be helpful.

Comment: i installed the app in 10 devices, on 8 of them I have the font

Comment: i installed the app on 10 devices. On 8 of them i have the propper font, on 2 of them it's the system font

Comment: @BogdanSomlea - I am sure you would have checked - but can you pl. confirm that the working and not working devices are on the same iOS version as well.

Comment: i tested on iOS 7.1.2 and on iOS 8 . Some of the devices with iOS 8 work, some not. but on all devices with iOS 7.1.2 it's working.

Comment: @BogdanSomlea - One more question - Are you using more than two variants - e.g. “Normal”, “Bold” and “Extended” of this Font? Apologies for too many questions - but this is a trickier issue - am trying to narrow down on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

using this code you check it your font OpenSans-CondensedLight in the familyNames or not
.
Read this tutorial may be this help you.

http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: if it works on some devices, that means, that the font name is correct.. right?

Comment: i think you remove the font file and add font file once again.

Answer (score -1):

Please click on font file and install it on your mac, now where this is installed get that name and put in fontWithName:

it will work surely.

Comment: and if i'm adding the app to the store, people who install the app from the store, will have that font too?.. don't really think so